# Can't click button inside a clickable div

Tags: html, css, reactjs, jsx, chakra-ui

I am using Chakra UI in react, When I am trying to click a Button inside a clickable Box, The function of Box is being executed. Z-index also not fixing the issue.

My code:

```
<Box
   w="90%"
   h="auto"
   mt="10px"
   position="relative"
   key={index}
   borderWidth="1px"
   borderRadius="lg"
   onClick={() =>
   history.push(`/products/${item.cat_name}/${item.id}`)}
>
 <h1 className={styles.heading_bold}>{item.cat_name}</h1>
<Button position="absolute" top="3" right="3" zIndex="0"> //Button not able to click
 Options
</Button
</Box>
```

[Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-euler-z10mn?file=/src/app.js)

Comment: please add sample code in codesandbox for debugging is better

Comment: its because of `event bubbling`. If you want to stop it you need to stop its propagation. Read more about this

Comment: @A.R.SEIF codesandbox link here https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-euler-z10mn?file=/src/app.js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be `onClick` not onclick.

```
   <Button
        onClick={() => console.log("button clicked")} // Typo fixed
        position="absolute"
        top="3"
        right="3"
        zIndex="0"
      >
```

Here is the `CodeSandbox:` https://codesandbox.io/s/debuuge-lwio5

Also note that `Button is` inside the `Box` so first `Button` handler gets invoked and then also the `Box` handler once button is clicked.

To  stop event from propagating you can use the following code.

```
  <Button
        onClick={(e) => {
          e.stopPropagation();
          console.log("button clicked");
        }}
        position="absolute"
        top="3"
        right="3"
        zIndex="0"
      >
```

Now whenever you click on Button only it's handler will get invoked and you will see, `button clicked` in the output.